# Problems installing Julia language on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, julia

I'm following instructions from [here](http://julialang.org/downloads/platform.html) (see Ubuntu section). It says me to do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:staticfloat/juliareleases
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:staticfloat/julia-deps
sudo apt-get update
```

But then the command

```
sudo apt-get install julia
```

Gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 julia : Depends: libcholmod1.7.1 but it is not installable or
              libcholmod2.1.2 but it is not installable or
              libcholmod3.0.6 but it is not installable
     Depends: libumfpack5.4.0 but it is not installable or
              libumfpack5.6.2 but it is not installable or
              libumfpack5.7.1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using Xubuntu 16.10.

Can you please help me to understand what is going on and how to solve it?

Comment: does installing them first work? ... try `sudo apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev` (which contains all of the packages listed)

Comment: @AlexanderMorley, I tried it now, it did not work. Same problem.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the binary and running it instead of using the PPA?

Comment: @ColinTBowers, no, not yet. I prefer PPA, but if it does not work soon, I am going to use the binaries.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that in diagnosing the problem with the PPA, it would be interesting to know whether the binary works or if it is similarly broken on your system (remember, the binary is the "official" method - the PPA is community maintained). If the binary similarly fails, it suggests that you might have an issue in your Ubuntu package ecosystem.

Comment: @ColinTBowers, now I get what you meant. :) As Daniel HØegh said, PPA is not updated anymore so it is probably broken. I am going to use the binaries. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PPA is not updated anymore and the generic Linux binaries should be used instead, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19136.